# Can I install a sync completion hook with rsync daemon?

Tags: rsync, hook

Like hooks in svn or git, can I install a server-side hook script for rsync daemon? For sync completion event.

I am using FreeBSD9/rsyncd.

Comment: Won't `rsync foo bar/ && echo "rsync finished"` do?

Comment: I wanted to run server-side command. But I also just realized that it's hard to choose how server-side program privileged.

Comment: @terdon It would be better to run it from client side just like you said. Thanks.